# If $f$ is defined on $X$ such that every compact set in $X$ is mapped to a compact set. Is $f$ a continuous map?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let
$$
f:X\rightarrow Y
$$

If $f$ is defined on $X$ such that every compact set in $X$ is mapped to a compact set in $Y$. Is $f$ a continuous map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Let

$$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x\le 0\\
1,&\text{if }x>0\;.
\end{cases}$$

clearly $f[A]$ is compact for *every* $A\subseteq\Bbb R$, but $f$ is certainly not continuous.

Comment: If $A=[-1,1]$ then is $f[A]=[0,1]$ or $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: @MrDi: The range of $f$ is the two-point set $\{0,1\}$; there is no $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=\frac12$, for instance. Thus, $f[A]=\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Is $\{0,1\}$ closed set?

Comment: @MrDi: Of course: every finite subset of $\Bbb R$ is closed.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous but $X$ is not compact then is it true that $f$ can't be uniformly continuous?

Comment: @MrDi: No: a constant function, for instance, is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - after reading several articles (and noticed the OP used this vernacular), is reading $f : X \to Y$ as “*$f$ is a $Y$ valued map on a set $X$*” an effective way of communicating the data of a map? *e.g.*, *$f$ is a real-valued map on a set $M$* means $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @TaylorRendon: In the case of *real-valued*, *integer-valued*, *complex-valued*, and perhaps *two-valued* it’s pretty standard, but *$Y$-valued* sounds a bit odd to me, though I expect that it would be understood.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - gotcha, that’s what I was thinking as well! Regarding the domain of the map $f : X \to Y$, do you think it would be better to say “$f$ is a map defined on $X$” or “$f$ is a map on $X$“? I’ve seen both, but I’d assume the former would be more precise.

Comment: @TaylorRendon: I would normally say simply that $f$ is a function (or occasionally a map) from $X$ to $Y$,

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - wonderful, thank you for your time answering my questions! (-:

Comment: @TaylorRendon: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be some topological space and $Y$ some finite topological space. Then every subset of $Y$ is compact, so every map $f \colon X \to Y$ maps compact sets to compact sets. But not every function into a finite topological space is continuous.